Overwriting feature layer using lyrx file
I am trying to come up with a method that utilizes lyrx files to routinely overwrite a feature layer on ArcGIS Portal. I've tried a few methods that utilize Python scripts, ModelBuilder and Task Scheduler to accomplish this, but I feel like the main issue is with the file format (lyrx).
I am back at square one with this, so any feedback/suggestions?
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]
layer = map.addDataFromPath(lyr_file_path)
outputfc_path = f"{outputgdb}/{outputfc_name}"
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features = layer, out_path = outputgdb, out_name = outputfc_name)
print(f"Feature class created at: {outputfc_path}")
        
gis = GIS(portalurl, username, password)
    item = gis.content.get(itemid)
    flayer_collection = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(item)
    flayer_collection.manager.overwrite(outputfc_path)
    try:
        flayer_collection.manager.overwrite(outputfc_path)
        print("Feature layer has been successfully overwritten with updated data.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during overwrite: {e}")

All my variables are assigned in a different section which shows personal info so i cant include it in the post. This has worked the best in terms of making the lyr into a feature class. However, when uploading to portal it says that it has been modifeid, but the feature count is not what it should be!

Is there a reason that you are using a lyrx file as opposed to it's geodatabase version/shapefile version/ etc.

i meant to say lyr instead of lyrx, sorry! its just what i have been given and represents the most current updated form of that data, so i am restrained to only using lyr files to overwrite the layer. i did update my original post to include the code, i tried an approach where i make a copy of the lyr in the form of a feature class, and it works perfectly, but the overwrite is causing problems

A layer file (lyr/lyrx) doesn't contain any data. It only contains a link to the underlying datasource and may also include symbology, definition query, labelling amongst other properties.  If someone has provided you with a layer file and not the underlying data, then you don't have everything you need.

You can use ArcPy to overwrite and avoid using the ArcGIS API for Python altogether. The basis of the code below are from a blog post here.
Note: for hosted feature services only.
import arcpy
import os

################################################################################
## INPUT REQUIRED  #############################################################

## the path to the APRX that contains the Map with the layers to publish
aprx_path = r""

## the name of the Map in the APRX that contains the layers to publish
map_name = "MAP NAME"

## a folder to stage the definition files
staging_fldr = r""

## some tags for our Hosted Feature Service
tags = "tag1,tag2,tag3"

## a description for our Hosted Feature Service
description = "This is our description"

## a summary for our Hosted Feature Service
summary = "This is our summary"

## overwrite the current feature service
overwrite = True

################################################################################
## ACCESS ARCGIS PRO COMPONENTS  ###############################################

## access the APRX
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)

## access the correct map
m = aprx.listMaps(map_name)[0]


################################################################################
## STAGING #####################################################################

## the service definition filenames and output paths
sddraft_output_filepath = os.path.join(staging_fldr, f"{map_name}.sddraft")
sd_output_filepath = os.path.join(staging_fldr, f"{map_name}.sd")

## if either of the output files already exists, then delete
if arcpy.Exists(sddraft_output_filepath):
    arcpy.Delete_management(sddraft_output_filepath)

if arcpy.Exists(sd_output_filepath):
    arcpy.Delete_management(sd_output_filepath)


################################################################################
## MANIPULATE THE SD DRAFT ######################################################

## use the Map object getWebLayerSharingDraft method
## returns a FeatureSharingDraft object
sd_draft = m.getWebLayerSharingDraft(
    server_type = "HOSTING_SERVER",
    service_type = "FEATURE",
    service_name = map_name
)

## alter some properties of the sd_draft
sd_draft.description = description
sd_draft.summary = summary
sd_draft.tags = tags
sd_draft.allowExporting = True
sd_draft.overwriteExistingService = overwrite

## create the Service Definition Draft file
sd_draft.exportToSDDraft(sddraft_output_filepath)


################################################################################
## STAGE THE SERVICE ###########################################################

## stage the service
arcpy.server.StageService(
    in_service_definition_draft = sddraft_output_filepath,
    out_service_definition = sd_output_filepath
)


################################################################################
## PUBLISH TO ARGIS ONLINE #####################################################

## publish to agol
arcpy.server.UploadServiceDefinition(
    in_sd_file = sd_output_filepath,
    in_server = "HOSTING_SERVER"
)


################################################################################

